# Can every integer $\geq 2$ be written as a linear combination of prime numbers with imposed conditions?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I wonder if the following conjecture can be proved either by elementary means, or by assuming known results like Vinogradov's theorem or Goldbach's weak conjecture or perhaps even unknown results like Goldbach's conjecture.

> Let $N\geq 2.$ Define $\mathbb{P}_{\leq N}$ to be the set of all
> primes $\leq N.$
>
> Conjecture: There exists a subset (sub-permutation) $\{x_1, x_2,
>  \ldots, x_n\}\ $ of $\ \left\{ 1,2,\ldots, \lceil \ln N \rceil
>  \right\}\ $ and a subset (sub-permutation) of $\{y_1, y_2, \ldots, y_n\}\ $ of
> $\mathbb{P}_{\leq N}$ such that $$ \sum_{k=1}^{n} x_k y_k = N. $$

I have checked for the first few values of $N$ by hand up to about $50,$ and also some values of $N$ in the hundreds and I didn't find any counter-examples.

Comment: Wrote a brute force program that checked up to $N=2000$, no counterexamples. For me, the conjecture seems easier than Vinogradov, although it does have a slightly different flavour.

Comment: @SomeCallMeTim thanks for doing that. Yes I agree this question has a slightly different flavour than Goldbach or Vinogradov, due to the permutations conditions.

Comment: Let $x_1 = \lceil \ln N \rceil$ and $y_1$ be largest prime not larget than $N / x_1$. Then if we have $N - x_1 y_1 < y_1$ (equal: $y_1 > N / (x_1 + 1)$), the problem is reduced to the same with smaller $N$. So if primes are dense enough that there is a prime between $\frac{N}{\lceil \ln N \rceil + 1}$ and $\frac{N}{\lceil \ln N \rceil}$, then the answer is "true". I think Dusart's result: for $x > 90000$ there is prime between $x$ and $(1 + 1/\ln^3 x) x$ - is enough for that. If it's so, we just need to check values of $n$ up to approximately 1'500'000.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x_1 = \lceil \ln N \rceil$ and $y_1$ be largest prime at most $\frac{N - 2}{x_1}$. Then, if $N - x_1 \cdot y_1 < y_1$, and statement is true for $N - x_1 \cdot y_1$, statement is true for $N$: take sum for $N - x_1\cdot y_1$ (it is at least $2$), it doesn't use primes larger than $y_1$, so if we add $x_1 \cdot y_1$ to this sum, we get correct decomposition for $N$.

$N - x_1 \cdot y_1 < y_1$ is equivalent to $y_1 > \frac{N}{\lceil \ln N \rceil + 1}$, so the question is if there is a prime between $\frac{N}{\lceil \ln N \rceil + 1}$ and $\frac{N - 2}{\lceil \ln N \rceil}$. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate#Better_results), Dusart proved that for $x \geq 89693$, there is a prime $p$ s.t. $x < p \leq \left(1 + \frac{1}{\ln^3 x}\right) x$. Taking $x = \frac{N}{\lceil \ln N\rceil + 1}$, this gives there is prime $p$ s.t.
$$\frac{N}{\lceil \ln N\rceil + 1} < p \leq \left(1 + \frac{1}{(\ln N - \ln(\lceil \ln N\rceil + 1))^3}\right) \cdot \frac{N}{\lceil \ln N\rceil + 1}$$

We need
$$\left(1 + \frac{1}{(\ln N - \ln(\lceil \ln N\rceil + 1))^3}\right) \cdot \frac{N}{\lceil \ln N\rceil + 1} \leq \frac{N - 2}{\lceil \ln N\rceil}$$
$$ \frac{N}{(\lceil \ln N\rceil) + 1)\cdot (\ln N - \ln(\lceil \ln N\rceil + 1))^3} \leq \frac{N}{\lceil \ln N\rceil \cdot (\lceil \ln N\rceil + 1)} - \frac{2}{\lceil \ln N \rceil}$$

Left part grows as $\frac{N}{\ln N^4}$, right as $\frac{N}{\ln N^2}$t, so eventually the inequality holds. Taking $N = 2^M$, we get

$$\frac{2^M}{(M + 1)\cdot(M - \ln(M + 1))^3} \leq \frac{2^M}{M \cdot (M + 1)} - \frac{2}{M}$$

[image: plot]

From plot by Wolfram (of course we can prove more rigorously), we can see that inequality holds for $M > 4$, or $N > 16$ - for example, for $17$ we can find first term as $x_1 = 3$, $y_1 = 5$.

Thus, we need to check values when $\frac{N}{\lceil \ln N \rceil + 1} < 89693$ - that is approximately $n < 1'500'000$. I created [colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1LpLjIJ8htIB5A0ipQ0ZMp0n92D_93myI?usp=sharing) that proves that the same method works also for $n$ from $17$ to $1'500'000$ - that matches other result claimed by wikipedia, that Riemann hypothesis implies there is prime s.t. $x - \frac{4}{\pi}\sqrt{x}\ln x < p \leq x$, which also is enough to justify this method.

Comment: This is a great idea, and a great answer. +1